# Stanford coreNLP Sentiment analysis for Spanish

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to do sentiment analysis in Spanish with Stanford CoreNLP.

**Is is possible to use Sentiment annotator in Spanish as well?**

Up to now I changed 'spanish.properties':

```
annotators =  tokenize, ssplit, pos, parse, sentiment

tokenize.language = es

sentiment.model = edu/stanford/nlp/international/spanish

pos.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/spanish/spanish-distsim.tagger

ner.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/spanish.ancora.distsim.s512.crf.ser.gz
ner.applyNumericClassifiers = false
ner.useSUTime = false

parse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/spanishPCFG.ser.gz


> initCoreNLP(type = "spanish")

[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Searching for resource: StanfordCoreNLP-spanish.properties
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
Error in rJava::.jnew("edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP",     basename(path)) : 
  java.lang.RuntimeException: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Error while loading a tagger model (probably missing model file)
```

I got this error and also the results is not correct

```
> text <- c("Estoy feliz.", "Estoy triste." , "No me gusta eso." ,"Estoy enojado.")
> string.text <- annotateString(text)
> getSentiment(string.text)
  id sentimentValue sentiment
1  1              2   Neutral
2  2              3  Positive
3  3              1  Negative
4  4              2   Neutral
```

Could you please help me how I can conduct Spanish Sentiment analysis in Stanford coreNLP?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Stanford CoreNLP does not support sentiment analysis for Spanish. You will have to look elsewhere for sentiment data / pre-trained models in Spanish.

(The actual error you are seeing is that the POS tagger is not on your classpath. Make sure you have downloaded the separate Spanish models JAR (available on the CoreNLP site) and that it is on your classpath.)